# How to perform Sql pivot without aggregation and with order by?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have Persons table As shown in image and i want to convert it into Table2

[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjE3h.png)

This is how I am Trying to build query in Sql Server but i don't know what to write in place of aggregate function and one more thing is that I want all person name  in alphabetical order in respective country as shown in image.

```
Select Usa ,India, Uk from Persons

pivot
(
Aggregate(i_dont_know) for Country in ([Usa],[India],[Uk])
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MAX/MIN` aggregate and `Row_number`

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY country ORDER BY NAME) AS rn,*
        FROM   Persons b) a
       PIVOT ( Max(NAME)
             FOR Country IN ([Usa],
                             [India],
                             [Uk]) ) pv 
order by rn
```

Without `Row_Number` you will get a `max` or `min` name for each country.

If the number of countries are unknown then

```
DECLARE @sql      VARCHAR(8000) ='',
        @col_list VARCHAR(8000)= ''

SELECT @col_list = (SELECT ',' + Quotename(NAME)
                    FROM   Persons
                    GROUP  BY NAME
                    FOR xml path(''))

SET @col_list = Stuff(@col_list, 1, 1, '')
SET @sql = 'SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY country ORDER BY NAME) AS rn,*
        FROM   Persons b) a
       PIVOT ( Max(NAME)
             FOR Country IN (' + @col_list
           + ') ) pv order by rn'

PRINT @sql

EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: @huzefa - are you getting any error ? It is just the dynamic version of first solution

Comment: no error but its not giving correct ans. btw i figure out it. in select statement instead of name we need to write country in quotename() and group by both

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, it's not a pivot but this way you get your names grouped:

```
select 
    max(case when country = 'Usa' then name end) as Usa,
    max(case when country = 'Uk' then name end) as Uk,
    max(case when country = 'India' then name end) as India
from
(
    select 
        name, 
        country, 
        row_number() over (partition by country order by name) as RN
    from persons
) X
group by RN
order by RN
```

Answer (score 0):

try this Aggregate MIN/MAX

```
SELECT Usa ,India, Uk from Persons
PIVOT
(   MIN([Name]) 
    FOR [Country] IN ([Usa], [India], [Uk]) 
)AS p
```